# Apache felix osgi unable to export package

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, amdatu

I have below set up in `manifest.mf` file,

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1359719312904
Bundle-Activator: org.amdatu.mongo.impl.Activator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: org.amdatu.mongo
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.amdatu.mongo
Bundle-Version: 1.0.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_09 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: org.amdatu.mongo;uses:="com.mongodb";version="1.0"
Import-Package: com.mongodb,org.amdatu.mongo;version="[1.0,2)",org.apach
 e.felix.dm;version="[3.0,4)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2)",org.o
 sgi.service.cm;version="[1.3,2)",org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)"
Private-Package: org.amdatu.mongo.impl
Tool: Bnd-1.51.0
```

When I install this bundle I am not getting org.amdatu.mongo package in export list in apache felix?
Please check the image below ...my bundle is in active plus running state.Still I am not able to see export package??

[image]

I have no package with ID 508 from which this bundle importing the org.amdatu.mongo

I have search in web console and I got only one bundle.Please check the image below,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that Felix is *unable* to export the package. It just doesn't need to.

You have listed the package `org.amdatu.mongo` as both an export and an import. This gives the OSGi Framework a choice: import it if there is an another bundle already exporting it; otherwise, export it.

So in other words you are seeing normal, correct behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I have check and found that there are no other bundle with id 508 from which these bundle importing the org.amdatu.mongo!!!

Comment: I have updated the question which shows there are no bundle with ID 508

Comment: I refresh the package ...and now all problems are resolved ...hopefully..

Comment: What problems? ;-)

Comment: I have used org.amdatu.mongo ..budle and its export its service via managedservicefactory.Do you know how to use it in my bundle ...I have used @dependencyReference annotation...and yes this service also listed in services tab..

Comment: This sounds like a new question.

Comment: hmm yes...service is listed in web console but still getting null